# How to clear out dynamic input field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with two radio buttons. Based on your selection your next field will change. There are some calculaltions that occur which I have already figured out. However my one problem is I am unable to clear out the text field if you switch between the radio buttons.

For the radio buttons there is a set state

```
<label style={{ paddingRight: 50 }}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="react-tips"
                value="option1"
                checked={this.state.selectedOption === "option1"}
                onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                className="form-check-input"
              />
              Transactions
            </label>
            <label style={{}}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="react-tips"
                value="option2"
                checked={this.state.selectedOption === "option2"}
                onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
                className="form-check-input"
              />
              Partners
            </label>
```

As you can see the **checked={this.state.selectedOption === "option1"}** Is what lets us know which radio button is selected.

From this there is conditional renderin of the text input:

```
let monthlyField;
if (this.state.selectedOption === "option1") {
  monthlyField = <div>
    <p> $250 per 250 monthly transactions, unlimited trading partners<br />Enter number of transactions per month: </p>
    <input  type="number" placeholder="250" onChange={this.onChangeMonthlyTransactions.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
} else {
  monthlyField = <div>
    <p> $250 per trading partner unlimited transactions <br />Enter number of trading partners: </p>
    <input type="number" placeholder="1" onChange={this.onChangeMonthlyPartners.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
}
```

Where in the render it will just be

```
 {monthlyField}
```

Now using this set state for the radio buttons I can use that to figure out which option has been selected in order to properly calculate

```
  //Calculating total cost


calculateTotal() {
if (this.state.selectedOption === "option1") {

  console.log("This is transaction based")
  var monthly = (Math.ceil(this.state.typedMonthly /250)) * 250
  var total =  monthly + this.state.fixedAmmount + (this.state.typedMapping * 750)
} else {
  console.log("This is partner based")
  var monthly = (Math.ceil(this.state.typedMonthlyTransaction)) * 250
  var total =  monthly + this.state.fixedAmmount + (this.state.typedMapping * 750)
}

return (
  <p>$ {total}</p> 
)
```

}

Everything works however, in my text field if I put in a number then switch to the other radio button the same text is still in the text field. I need that to clear out.

An example is in this gif. https://recordit.co/F1WXBgeWB4

The text box does not clear when I switch between radio buttons. The calculation at the bottom works exactly as it should (ie. It resets when changed)

EDIT: On change for radio button code

```
  handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
this.setState({
  selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value
});


};
```

Comment: will you please add code for the `onChange` method of the radio buttons? You'll need to add a statement to that function that checks if those text fields have content, and if so then clear them.

Comment: Is it really needed to check if the text fields have already content? Isn't it enough to just put them to empty on change?

Comment: @Lykos94 That should be enough, yeah!

Comment: @MikeAbeln I have added it. Its only state change there.

Comment: @Lykos94 yes just putting them on empty is exactly what I want to do. However im not sure how to do that. How do I access the input field to make it empty?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is a missing double binding between a variable in the states and your input. This can be solved with

```
if (this.state.selectedOption === "option1") {
  monthlyField = <div>
    <p> $250 per 250 monthly transactions, unlimited trading partners<br />Enter number of transactions per month: </p>
    <input  type="number" value={this.state.inputValue} placeholder="250" onChange={this.onChangeMonthlyTransactions.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
} else {
  monthlyField = <div>
    <p> $250 per trading partner unlimited transactions <br />Enter number of trading partners: </p>
    <input type="number" value={this.state.inputValue} placeholder="1" onChange={this.onChangeMonthlyPartners.bind(this)}/>
  </div>
}
```

Note the `value` field added. Also remember to create the variable in the constructor. At this point:

```
handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
    this.setState({
      selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value,
      inputValue: ''
    });
};
```

For more information about that, check out the [Forms Documentation](https://it.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)